TabView tabItem makes items to align verticaly SwiftUI, tabItem not applying style
So I have this style for my label that makes icon and text aligned horizontally, It works fine out of tabItem

But once I add that to the tabItem in TabView the icon and the text become vertically aligned again as in VStack.

Please advise am I doing something wrong?
Is there any extra set up for this? I couldn't find it

Tabview does not really enable to change label style for tab items. These are always image on top and text at bottom.

You might want to implement a custom tab bar instead, then you can style the labels any way you like. The answer to SwiftUi Change Tint of Unselected Item in Tab Bar shows how it can be done.

thank you guys, I will update the question

Thanks to the commentors!
From them:
Tabview does not really enable to change label style for tab items. These are always image on top and text at bottom
You might want to implement a custom tab bar instead, then you can style the labels any way you like. The answer to SwiftUi Change Tint of Unselected Item in Tab Bar  shows how it can be done.
